# Closest points (coordinates) given one point

Tags: python

I have a list of points which represent x and y coordinates:

```
[(82.62000274658203, 79.7300033569336), (82.72000122070312, 79.56999969482422), (82.81999969482422, 80.06999969482422), (82.20999908447266, 80.5999984741211), (81.95999908447266, 80.29239654541016), (81.44000244140625, 81.08999633789062), (80.9000015258789, 81.48999786376953), ...
```

[image]

Given one point (the red point), how can I find, say 8, of the closest points to that 1 point. Any particular algorithm or method?

Comment: Iterate over all points and keep track of the best 8. If you don't have a very large number of points just calculate the distance to all of them, then sort and take the first 8 elements.

Comment: If you have many points, you have to do fewer comparisons. In that case you need a different data structure. I'd recommend you take a look at [Quad trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree)

Comment: Isn't the obvious method to iterate over all the points and find their distance from the red point, then sort the distances and find the first 8 closest. You could even do this in one sort of a list where the key function calculates distance - the key function will only be called once/list entry so not wasteful, but if it is too slow then consider optimisations. No need to calucalte square root of separation. If there are a gazillion points to compare with red then you can eliminate a large proportion without calculating squared distance just by subtracting the x and y.

Comment: You're describing an algorithm called K-NN (stands for K-Nearest-Neighbors). It is typically time complexity of `O(nd)` where `n` is the number of points and `d` is the dimensionality of the vector, but there are tons of approximate versions and there might be an optimal version for the case when `d=2`, like in your case.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki if the set of comparison points doesn't change while the queries keep coming all the time, then it may be reasonable to look for a faster algorithm, i.e., better than just a naive linear search.

Comment: For that problem, Voronoi Diagrams Theory is a good solution. I'm sure there're lot of examples to search. As an example: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-create-voronoi-regions-with-geospatial-data-in-python-adbb6c5f2134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try something like:

```
def pClosest(points, origin, K):

  points.sort(key = lambda K: (K[0]-origin[0])**2 + (K[1]-origin[1])**2)

  return points[:K]

# Driver program
points = [[3, 3], [5, -1], [-2, 4]]
origin = [3,3]

K = 2

print(pClosest(points, origin, K))
```